# Why can't I vote to reopen ny hastily closed question now I edited it?

Tags: support

Why can't I vote to reopen ny hastily closed question now I edited it?

Answer (score 5):

Voting to reopen is [a privilege](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) that you do not have earned yet.

Comment: i'm starting a gofundme